# How to add custom block above footer

Tags: magento-1.9, php, blocks

I'm trying to add custom block above the footer. I'm adding my custom block in `page.xml`:

```
<block type="core/template" template="page/html/socmed_footer.phtml" name="socmed_footer" as="socmed_footer" />
```

Then i create `socmed_footer.phtml` in `/page/html/socmed_footer.phtml`

```
<div class="socmed_footer">
   <div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
   <div class="line">Line</div>
   <div class="instagram">Instagram</div>
</div>
```

Then i called the custom block in `footer.phtml`

```
<div class="footer-container">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('socmed_footer') ?>
<div class="footer">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
    <address class="copyright"><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>
</div>
```

It's working, but why my footer showing duplicate `socmed_footer.phtml` inside `footer-container` and also `footer` class?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why duplicate socmed_footer.phtml inside footer-container and also footer class**

As at  *footer.phtml*,you have call *getChildHtml()*  so ***it is automatically call all child blocks of footer block***.

For this issue you need to remove `$this->getChildHtml('socmed_footer')` or

Remove **socmed_footer** block from layout code and call this `socmed_footer`
Progratcally at footer.phtml using below code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('page/html/socmed_footer.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that call `getChildHtml()`draws all blocks. You need to specify a certain block that should be drawn in case you want to avoid this problem.

Comment: This is correct, but i have to define each childhtml, thanks btw!